# Angularjs HTTP embedded controllers and binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm another Angular newbie. I have followed a good video course to get me started, and am now trying to phase out JQuery and use Angular in a current app development. The one thing the course didn't cover is the following issue I am stuck on.

I am using Angular's HTTP service to load some records within a page. The records are generated and templated by php so all angular is doing is getting that output and loading it into a template and displaying it in the page. Each record has the usual set of buttons, edit, deleted etc. I want to use click events on these that will be handled by an angular  controller. At the moment I am simply trying to produce an alert for the sake of testing. I have tried wrapping a controller div around the buttons, and adding `ng-click="someFunction()"` to the buttons, but they seem to be well and truly out of scope and nothing fires.

My question is, how do I get angular to work with html content that is loaded via HTTP i.e. adding a controller within the content that is being loaded?

Comment: Could you please add a code example.

Comment: Although loading the HTML partial content is *not the way to go* when using Angular, what you really need is to [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) the content before attaching it to the DOM. Do take care to cleanup after yourself in this case.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos, I originally had Angular passing all the content using `ng-repeat` but that would intermittently crash the browser. I will look further into `$compile` thanks.